# explicit flush() in a transactional method will update database or not

Tags: hibernate

in my app i have a service layer where the spring transaction boundary is declared for all the methods inside this service. service layer interally contact dao. here my question if specify getHibernateTemplate.flush() in dao methods, will it immedieatly update db or until the service layer method complets, it wont commit the changes. please help me here.

```
class someservice{
   public void somemethod(){
     activitydao.save(domainobj);
   }
}
class ActivityDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{
public void save(domainobj){
  getHibernateTemplate().save(domainobj);
  getHibernateTemplate().flush(); ----> will it update db immediately ?
}
}
```

Thanks,
Ramki.

Answer (score 8):

`flush()` will do the dirty check for all persistent entities managed by that hibernate session. If a persistent entity is dirty , hibernate will just issue the UPDATE  SQL to the DB immediately .

However ,just issuing the UPDATE SQL does not mean that the  data is actually saved to the DB ,you have to commit the transaction in order to  confirm saving  the data  to the DB  actually.  So , `flush()` only issues the UPDATE SQL without any COMMIT to the DB means that you can rollback the data if any errors are found later.

As you use Spring to manage the transaction ,transaction  will commit automatically if your method returns succesfully .In case of any exceptions throw before the method return , the transaction will rollback automatically .

Comment: thanks for quick answer. i will explain my problem little bit in details.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. i will explain my problem little bit in details.
i have following classes
1) jms listener which will listen on a queue.
2) ThreadPoolDeligator which will contain some 10 threads.
3) RequestExecutor(is a runnable class) which get process request by getting the servicelayer object
4)service class 5) dao class.
when ever jms receives a message, it will deligate to threadpool executor,which will internally call RequestExecutor(3) to execute it ,it will internally use service method for processing.

Comment: servcie method internally will make some changes to db and send will send a message back to queue which picked by other system and process it and again send the request to my system. this request will be executed by another thread.

Comment: here the problem is changes done by 1 thread is not visible to 2 thread.please help me here to solve this.

Comment: there is a some time gap(may be some milliseconds) between these two threads. but here i am able to see changes in db. but they are not visible to thread2.

Comment: you should post this question as another new questions to let more people know it .Also, mark the question with more related tags can get let more people interested in the tags you marked to find your question